# Axis2 stubs generation issue

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, apache-axis, stubs

I generated Java stubs from WSDL using apache axis2, Apache tomcat 6 server instance for a SOAP web service.
The generated stubs contains lots of errors(100) some of them were duplicate methods and there was some unusual error which said ARRAY.length can not resolve the type or some thing like that.
I can not compile stubs because of this errors.Is this a bug of axis2 or why this happens?

Comment: You need to supply more information than this. How are you running the wsdl2java step? What arguments or parameters are you supplying to wsdl2java? Can you attach the wsdl here? Better yet would be to strip the wsdl down to a simpler, smaller version (with only one operation, for example) that still displays the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you cannot compile the stubs? These stubs are really big files which are complex to understand. You dont need to worry about the warnings, To compile the files always add all axis2 libarries in the classpath. That will work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was with WSDL which was generated by .net application. of which some methods were returning .net specific data types.